# Insert removes backslash

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

With Entity Framework I'm inserting a json string with all quotes escaped. 
For example:
 `"{\"PDFName\":\"Test \",\"PDFDesc\":\"test desc\"}"`

Somehow the backslashes are getting removed from my string before the insert and the value in the database is:

`"{"PDFName":"Test ","PDFDesc":"test desc"}"`

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you looked at the debugger display and saw those slashes? They are not really in the string. The debugger shows them as such though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're missing one level of "escapes". I.e. escape your string once more (essentially replacing all the `\` with `\\`; but don't foget about non-escaped " as well).

Similar things happen in other cases, e.g. when using a string in a SQL statement,